# ASP.NET MVC no AccountController

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to learn ASP.NET MVC.

In all tutorials if they will create a new project with MVC, they have **Startup.Auth.cs** and **AccountController** in Controllers. In Web.config they have markups which allow them to **connect to database**. In Controllers I have only the **HomeController**

I don't have that. Why? They are usually using VISUAL STUDIO 2013, I have 2017 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to change Authentication to user with database when we are starting our new project.

[image: solve]